# MySQL огромный объем данных из текстового файла

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, вопрос скорее познавательный, чем практический. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Имеется файл с огромным количеством текста (около 5тыс строк), который в виде (.txt) - файла весят приблизительно 1МБ (именно мегабайт, а не гигабайт), но когда я импортирую этот файл в MySql,с условием, что каждая строка в текстовом файле - это новая строка в таблице, через phpmyadmin, размер созданной таблицы значительно возрастает в десятки раз, намного больше чем исходный размер файла, тем самым текст файла весящий изначально около 150КБ имеет вес в более чем 20-50МБ

Это нормально или нет? (я новичок в sql) 
И от чего это зависит?

p.s. таких файлов у меня несколько штук и вместе они весят около 2 МБ, а при импорте в базу, таблица вместо 2МБ весит уже более 3 ГБ, 
 (Что за несправедливость :-)  )

Вот пример запроса к бд.

```
INSERT INTO `anecd`  
(`text`, `type`)
VALUES  
 ('
 Идет чукча по перрону вдоль состава и в каждый вагон головой бьется. Его спрашивают:
 - Ты что это вагоны портишь?
 - Да у меня билет в мягкий вагон - вот и ищу...
','chukcha'),
 ('
 Поймали чукчу за кражу золота. Милиционер допрашивает, а другой чукча переводит:
 - Куда спрятал золото, - спрашивает милиционер.
 - Он, говорит, не брал, - переводит чукча.
 - Скажи ему, - говорит милиционер, - если сейчас же не скажет, то прикажу его расстрелять.
 - Он говорит, не скажешь, где золото, стрелять тебя немножко будет.
 - Под ярангой в кувшине зарыл, - признался вор.
 - Он говорит, - перевел чукча, - стреляй! Все равно не скажу.
','chukcha'),
 ('
 Чукча звонит в справочное бюро аэропорта:
 - Сколько летит самолет до Нарьян-Мара?
 - Минуточку, - отвечают в справочном.
 - Спасибо, - говорит чукча и вешает трубку.
','chukcha'),
```

Выглядит база так

```
------------------------------
id    |    text   |     type |
------------------------------
ID- int, AI, primary,11символов
TEXT-text (без ограничений)
TYPE-varchar-255символов
```

Индексируется по айди (1,2,3,....)
текст - место где пиется сам текст,
тип- у своей категории свой, например в примере выше - chukcha

### изменение:

Спасибо за помощь, ответ оказался в том, что загружается (содается) строк в таблице больше чем надо, возможно из-за большого объема строк или из-за кокого-то сбоя, теперь попробую решить эту проблему (я пользуюсь программой Super Dumper 2)

В моем файле запроса содержится чуть больше 11198 строк, которые надо загрузить в таблицу, но Dumper 2 их почему-то накручивает больше (именно накручивает) т.к. пишет, что всё загружено, а сам догружает ещё те же самые строки. (тем самым из 11тысяч строк получается 150тыс. строк)(пока я писал это, он добавил около 533тыс. строк)

Было такое у кого-нибудь? 
или может есть программа наподобии Dumper 2, которая не "самодельничает" без спросу :-) ?

p.s. использую Dumper 2 т.к. огромный объем данных phpmyadmin обрабатывает годами

Comment: Может и нормально, а может и нет. может быть надо как то оптимизировать структуру таблицы или отказаться от части индексов, если их много.

Comment: структура таблицы то какая у вас там? и сколько полей в строке?

Comment: Текст это текст, а таблицы это еще куча доп инфы помимо текста

Comment: типы данных у колонок какие и какие индексы созданы по таблице

Comment: Улыбнуло - огромный файл 5 тыс строк :)